# How to take webcam snapshot on login in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, email, authentication, webcam

I need a program which can take snapshot using my notebook webcam and send me email with it when someone else logs in. "Someone else" here means that it needs ability to identify me - I thinking about some special keyboard combination which I will press within the next minute after login. So if combination is pressed - it is me, otherwise - someone else, then take snapshot and send email.

I have good PHP phogramming skills but it wont help me with webcam and keyboard part of that idea.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/615330/webcam-automatically-takes-picture-when-the-computer-wakes-up and https://superuser.com/questions/888838/taking-a-picture-via-the-webcam-when-someone-logs-in-or-tries-to-log-in-on-wind

Comment: Super User isn't a code-writing service. Please see https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @wysiwyg As of similar question about webcam is seems to be valid to ask this sort of help. Btw it is not code-writing request, it is an ask for existing solutions. Google is overspamed by solutions which not fit my needs so I did't find required software in all that mess.

Comment: You mentioned your PHP programming skills, which I understood to mean you were asking for coding help. Whoever migrated your question to Stack Overflow apparently felt the same. Either way, if you are asking for software recommendations that certainly would be off-topic for Super User. Perhaps try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com